# programmatically select a row based on gridview values

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

#### What I have

I have a DataGridView with 3 columns (metric_key, metric_name, metric_value).

There are for example, 6 ROWS in this table (6 different metrics), added programmatically (DGV is not bound in any way)

Now, when I assign values in my grid I do:

```
dataGridView1.item("Metric_value",0).value = "value of the metric in row 0, in the column named "metric_Value".
```

#### What I'd like

However I'm looking for a way to use the value in the `metric_Key` column to do my assignment, something like:

```
datagridView1.item("metric_Value","My_metric_Key")
```

instead of putting the row ID, or maybe:

```
datagridview1.item("metric_value",Indexof("My_metric_Key"))
```

Or

```
datagridview1.item("metric_value",findValue("my_metric_key","metric_key"))
```

etc.

I don't want to create any other objects (dataview, etc.).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a built in way to do this.  But you can define an extension method on DataGridView to accomplish this.

```
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
Function FindValue(ByRef dgv As DataGridView, ByVal metric_key As Object) As DataGridViewRow
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgv.Rows
        If row.Cells.Item("metric_value").Value = metric_key Then
            Return row
        End If
    Next
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

So if you wanted to get the row where the metric_value is 1, you could use

```
dataGridView1.FindValue(1)
```

Comment: Nice!  and where can I put this code ? in a simple code file added to my project (like MyFunction.vb) ?

Comment: @simonlabdes.  Put the extension method code in a module added to your solution.  And in the code file where you use the code, add an <code>Imports</code> statement to import the module.