# How to get the rowindex by searching text from datagridview on vbnet

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, rows

I am stuck on a simple thing. My app has a `datagridview` with 3 columns. One columnshave the name "Sites" and I have added the rows to it as in: sites1, site2, etc.

What I want is for it to give me the simple function code to get the `rowindex` by searching the name of the site, like site1, from the "Sites" column.

I am messing with the below function but failed. Does you can please modified below function for me. So by this I will be able to get the rowindex by searching site value like site1, site2 etc.

```
Function FindValue(ByRef dgv As DataGridView, ByVal metric_key As Object) As DataGridViewRow
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgv.Rows
    If row.Cells.Item("metric_value").Value = metric_key Then
        Return row
    End If
Next
Return Nothing
```

End Function

Usage of function
dataGridView1.FindValue(1)

Finally I found the way by my self to find the rowindex by value

Here is mine code

```
Dim rowindex As String
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
  If row.Cells.Item("yourcolumnnamehere").Value = "valueforwhichyouaresearching" Then
    rowindex = row.Index.ToString()
    MsgBox(rowindex)
```

Comment: SO is not really the place to say "give it to me". We generally prefer to hear "I've tried X and X_q1 doesn't work. Can you help?". Citing inexperience is not an excuse to not try, so, what have you tried?

Comment: I was tried many functions and lots of codes. I waste my about 4 hours for trying this but cant get any result. One of the method which I was tried is TextBox1.Text = ""
Dim FirstValue As Boolean =  True 
Dim cell As DataGridViewCell
For Each cell In DataGridView1.SelectedCells
    If Not FirstValue Then
        TextBox1.Text += ", "
    End If
    TextBox1.Text += cell.Value.ToString()
    FirstValue = False
Next

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean ...

```
For Each cell In DataGridView1.SelectedCells 
  If Not FirstValue Then 
    TextBox1.Text += cell.Value.ToString()  & ", " 
  Else
    TextBox1.Text += cell.Value.ToString() 
    FirstValue= False 
  End If 

Next
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but its not working. I want to get the rowindex by searching value. Like the first column is of the sites and its contains many rows of sites. Like row 1 google.com, row 2 yahoo.com. So I want to find the rowindex by searching the value like "google.com" or "yahoo.com". I have found a http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228278/datagridview-programmatically-select-a-row-based-on-values-find-in-the-grid , where somebody have replied to how to find rowindex by value. But it have 2 columns. Please see that url and you can easily modified it for me. Again very thanks!