# Search dgv column by Column("TagIndex = 5")

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to get data from a DGV grid onto specific tags, and so far it has been working great. But an update moved the tags positions in the DGV so `Rows(x)` does not equal the tags I'm moving data into anymore.

Is it possible to do a search like the one I'm doing in `Cells("Val")` but in the `Rows("")` instead?
Actually I want it to be something like this `Rows("TagIndex = 5")` etc.

A full line of code would then be:

```
HopperStatus = dgvDataFlt.Rows("TagIndex = 5").Cells("Val").Value
```

but is this possible.

**Row 12 & 13 are switched when logging**
[image: Row 12 & 13 are switched when logging]

dgvDataFLT = dgvData*Floating*

```
If dgvDataFlt.Rows(0).Cells("TagIndex").Value = 12 Then                         
   'DGVDataFlt.AutoResizeColumns()
   '--------------------------------------Floating TAGS fra database------------------------------------------
    ProdRecCnt = dgvDataFlt.Rows(10).Cells("Val").Value  
    ProdTotCnt = dgvDataFlt.Rows(9).Cells("Val").Value   
    FrontFree = dgvDataFlt.Rows(8).Cells("Val").Value    
    CurrAutoMode = dgvDataFlt.Rows(7).Cells("Val").Value  
    PalletStatus = dgvDataFlt.Rows(6).Cells("Val").Value  
    HopperStatus = dgvDataFlt.Rows(5).Cells("Val").Value  
    PowerStatus = dgvDataFlt.Rows(4).Cells("Val").Value   
    CurrRecNo = dgvDataFlt.Rows(3).Cells("Val").Value     
    NomCycTime = dgvDataFlt.Rows(2).Cells("Val").Value    
    AutoStart = dgvDataFlt.Rows(1).Cells("Val").Value    
    MachineNo = dgvDataFlt.Rows(0).Cells("Val").Value    
    LOGTimeStamp = dgvDataFlt.Rows(0).Cells("DateAndTime").Value 'for aktuelle lognings tidstempel
    LOGDateStamp = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(LOGTimeStamp, 10) 
    LOGClockStamp = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Mid(LOGTimeStamp, 12, 5)                         
End If
```

I want the code to look/work something like this:

```
If dgvDataFlt.Rows(0).Cells("TagIndex").Value = 12 Then                         
   'DGVDataFlt.AutoResizeColumns()
   '--------------------------------------Floating TAGS fra database------------------------------------------
    ProdRecCnt = dgvDataFlt.Rows("TagIndex = 10").Cells("Val").Value  
    ProdTotCnt = dgvDataFlt.Rows("TagIndex = 9").Cells("Val").Value   
    FrontFree = dgvDataFlt.Rows("TagIndex = 8").Cells("Val").Value    
    CurrAutoMode = dgvDataFlt.Rows("TagIndex = 7").Cells("Val").Value  
    PalletStatus = dgvDataFlt.Rows("TagIndex = 6").Cells("Val").Value  
    HopperStatus = dgvDataFlt.Rows("TagIndex = 5").Cells("Val").Value  
    PowerStatus = dgvDataFlt.Rows("TagIndex = 4").Cells("Val").Value   
    CurrRecNo = dgvDataFlt.Rows("TagIndex = 3").Cells("Val").Value     
    NomCycTime = dgvDataFlt.Rows("TagIndex = 2").Cells("Val").Value    
    AutoStart = dgvDataFlt.Rows("TagIndex = 1").Cells("Val").Value    
    MachineNo = dgvDataFlt.Rows("TagIndex = 0").Cells("Val").Value    
    LOGTimeStamp = dgvDataFlt.Rows(0).Cells("DateAndTime").Value 'for aktuelle lognings tidstempel
    LOGDateStamp = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(LOGTimeStamp, 10) 
    LOGClockStamp = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Mid(LOGTimeStamp, 12, 5)
End If
```

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "tags".

Comment: Sorry, I'm used to PLC programming. 
By _TAGS_ I mean the defined integers like **ProdRecCnt** & **HopperStatus** etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [programmatically select a row based on gridview values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228278/programmatically-select-a-row-based-on-gridview-values)

Comment: How you populate DataGridView with the data?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding a class and then inheriting the DataGridView control into that class.  I have made a quick little example of this and the code works, but to get it to work you will have to perform a few steps:

(1)  If you don't already have a windows forms application to test this then, 
     make a new one.
(2)  Create class named KeyedDataGridView

(3)  Copy and Paste the following Code into KeyedDataGridView class

(4)  Rebuild your Project

(5)  Drag and Drop new component onto your windows Form.

NOTE:  This class is limited, but should still be able to do what you require of it.

Finally, if you need any help then, please leave a comment and will try to get to it when I can.

```
    Option Explicit On

    Public Class KeyedDataGridView
        Inherits Windows.Forms.DataGridView

        Dim _Rows As KeyedDataRows

        Public Shadows Property Rows As KeyedDataRows
            Get
                Return _Rows
            End Get
            Set(value As KeyedDataRows)
                _Rows = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Sub New()
            Dim strName As String

            strName = Me.Name

            strName = MyBase.Name

            _Rows = New KeyedDataRows(Me)
            _Rows.Rows = MyBase.Rows
        End Sub

        Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
            _Rows = Nothing

            MyBase.Finalize()
        End Sub
    End Class


    Public Class KeyedDataRows
        Inherits Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection

        Dim _TagNames As Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
        Dim _Rows As DataGridViewRowCollection
        Dim _Cells As Dictionary(Of String, DataGridViewCellCollection)
        Dim dgv As DataGridView

        Default Public Overloads ReadOnly Property Item(strTagName As String) As DataGridViewRow
            Get
                Return _Rows.Item(Me.IndexFromName(strTagName))
            End Get
        End Property

        Protected Friend Property Rows As DataGridViewRowCollection
            Get
                Return _Rows
            End Get
            Set(value As DataGridViewRowCollection)
                _Rows = value
            End Set
        End Property



        Public Property TagName(index As Integer) As String
            Get
                Return CStr(_TagNames.Item(index))
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                _TagNames.Item(index) = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Sub New(tmp As DataGridView)
            MyBase.New(tmp)

            dgv = tmp

            _TagNames = New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
            _Cells = New Dictionary(Of String, DataGridViewCellCollection)
        End Sub

        Public Shadows Sub Add(strTagName As String)
            Dim intCurRow As Integer

            If dgv.AllowUserToAddRows Then
                intCurRow = _Rows.Count - 1
            Else
                intCurRow = _Rows.Count
            End If
            _TagNames.Add(strTagName, intCurRow)
            _Rows.Add()
        End Sub

        Public Shadows Sub Add(strTagName As String, dataGridViewRow As DataGridViewRow)
            Dim intCurRow As Integer

            If dgv.AllowUserToAddRows Then
                intCurRow = _Rows.Count - 1
            Else
                intCurRow = _Rows.Count
            End If
            _TagNames.Add(strTagName, intCurRow)
            _Rows.Add(dataGridViewRow)
        End Sub

        Public Shadows Sub Add(count As Integer, strTagNames() As String)
            Dim intI As Integer
            Dim intCurRow As Integer

            If dgv.AllowUserToAddRows Then
                intCurRow = _Rows.Count - 1
            Else
                intCurRow = _Rows.Count
            End If
            For intI = 0 To (count - 1)
                _TagNames.Add(strTagNames(intI), intCurRow)
                _Rows.Add()

                intCurRow = _Rows.Count - 1
            Next intI
        End Sub

        Public Property IndexFromName(strTagName As String) As Integer

            Get
                If _TagNames.Count > 0 Then
                    If _TagNames.ContainsKey(strTagName) Then
                        Return _TagNames.Item(strTagName)
                    Else
                        Return -1
                    End If
                Else
                    Return -1
                End If
            End Get
            Set(value As Integer)
                _TagNames.Add(strTagName, value)
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Overloads Sub RemoveAt(strTagName As String)
            _Cells.Remove(strTagName)
            _Rows.RemoveAt(IndexFromName(strTagName))
            _TagNames.Remove(strTagName)
        End Sub


        Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
            _TagNames.Clear()
            _TagNames = Nothing

            _Cells.Clear()
            _Rows.Clear()

            _Cells = Nothing
            _Rows = Nothing

            MyBase.Finalize()
        End Sub
    End Class
```

I also, added the following buttons to a windows form to test the code:

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        With KeyedDataGridView1
            .Rows.Add("Tag Test 1")

            .Rows.Add("Tag Test 2")

            .Rows.Add("Tag Test 3")

            .Rows.Add("Tag Test 4")
        End With
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        MsgBox(KeyedDataGridView1.Rows("Tag Test 3").Cells(0).Value & vbCrLf &
               KeyedDataGridView1.Rows("Tag Test 3").Cells(1).Value & vbCrLf &
               KeyedDataGridView1.Rows("Tag Test 3").Cells(2).Value)
        MsgBox(KeyedDataGridView1.Rows("Tag Test 2").Cells(0).Value & vbCrLf &
               KeyedDataGridView1.Rows("Tag Test 2").Cells(1).Value & vbCrLf &
               KeyedDataGridView1.Rows("Tag Test 2").Cells(2).Value)
        MsgBox(KeyedDataGridView1.Rows("Tag Test 1").Cells(0).Value & vbCrLf &
               KeyedDataGridView1.Rows("Tag Test 1").Cells(1).Value & vbCrLf &
               KeyedDataGridView1.Rows("Tag Test 1").Cells(2).Value)

    End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but as of now I've got the logs to show in the right order by starting from scratch. 
If I run into the problem again, I will give your example a go :)